# How to read & count XML records from a file in UNIX shell Script

Tags: unix

I have records inside the XML tags, and I want to get the count of them. In below, e.g. the contents inside the `<record> </record>` tag should be counted as 1. So for the example below, the count should be 2:

```
<record>
    hi
    hello
</record>

<record>
    follow
</record>
```

Could somebody help me with the Unix Shell Script?

Comment: You are not going to include a sample of your data ?

Comment: <error_records>

<record record_no = "1" error_code="100">&apos;NULL&apos;;&apos;C20557&apos;;&apos;090&apos;;&apos;NULL&apos;
</record>

<record record_no = "5" error_code="101">&apos;NULL&apos;;&apos;20557&apos;;&apos;090&apos;;&apos;NULL&apos;
</record>

</error_records>         here the count should be two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work even if the file content is in single line(not in pretty XML format).

```
perl -nle "print s/<record>//g" < filename | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your XML is in a file named file.xml, your solution would be

```
grep "<record>" file.xml  | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -c "</record>" file.xml
```